# where is devise implementation of "authenticate_user!" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, oauth-2.0

Where is devise implementation of `authenticate_user!` method?

I have been looking for it and have not found it so far.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's in `lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`[1](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) and is generated dynamically (user being only one of the possible suffixes):

```
def self.define_helpers(mapping) #:nodoc:
    mapping = mapping.name

    class_eval <<-METHODS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
        opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
        warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
      end

      def #{mapping}_signed_in?
        !!current_#{mapping}
      end

      def current_#{mapping}
        @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :#{mapping})
      end

      def #{mapping}_session
        current_#{mapping} && warden.session(:#{mapping})
      end
    METHODS

    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
      helper_method "current_#{mapping}", "#{mapping}_signed_in?", "#{mapping}_session"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237346/what-is-code-for-devise-authenticate-user-after-generated-for-user

Comment: so how do I access it explicity. this call doesn't work>> `Devise::Controllers::Helpers.authenticate_user!`

Answer (score 25):

When you add devise to rails, you'll typically add in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :user
```

This is defined in the [Devise Mapper class](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb).

which calls `Devise.add_mapping` for every resource passes to `devise_for`

the Devise module's add_mapping method is defined [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb), which subsequently calls `define_helpers`, which defines `authenticate` as discussed in other answers.

Answer (score 7):

It's declared using some metaprogramming here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L46-49

```
class_eval <<-METHODS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
  def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
    opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
    warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
  end
  ...
end
```