# Direct link login with devise but getting Filter chain halted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

So, I'm trying to do a direct login link using the authentication token but I'm getting `Filter chain halted as :after_token_authentication rendered or redirected` in my server logs

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery
      before_filter :store_location
      before_filter :authenticate_user!
      before_filter :after_token_authentication
      check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?

      rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
        session[:previous_url] = nil
        redirect_to root_url
      end


      def store_location
        # reset_session
        # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.

        if (request.fullpath != "/user/sign_in" && \
            request.fullpath != "/user/sign_up" && \
            request.fullpath != "/user/password" && \
            !request.fullpath.include?("/user") && \
            !request.fullpath.include?("/admin") && \
            !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
          session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
        end
      end

      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if current_user.admin?
          admin_dashboard_path
        elsif current_user.contractor?
          if current_user.contractor.business_name == 'Test Devise'
            'url'
          else
            contractor_dashboard_path
          end
        else
          session[:previous_url] || homeowner_service_requests_path
        end
      end

      #generates 6-digit random password (a-z, 0-9) for sending to users when BuildZoom creates user account after they express interest in a service request, leave a review
      def generate_temporary_password
        rand(36**6).to_s(36)
      end




      protected


      def after_token_authentication
    if params[:authentication_key].present?
      @user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:authentication_key])
      sign_in @user if @user
      welcome = @user.approved.eql?(7) and @user.type.eql?(2)
      @user.approved = 0
      @user.save
      unless welcome
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        redirect_to contractor_welcome_path
      end
    elsif params[:auth_token].present? && params[:location] == "galleries"
       @current_user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:auth_token])
        sign_in @current_user if @current_user
        @current_user.approved = 0
        @current_user.save
        debugger
      redirect_to contractor_list_galleries_path
    end
  end

      def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
        'url'
      end
    end
```

Here is the server log:

```
    Started GET "/?auth_token=uN8QFMsocpDyhWKCx9QN&location=galleries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 22:38:37 -0700
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"uN8QFMsocpDyhWKCx9QN", "location"=>"galleries"}
Geokit is using the domain:
  User Load (189.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`authentication_token` = 'uN8QFMsocpDyhWKCx9QN' LIMIT 1
   (109.5ms)  BEGIN
   (111.7ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2013-09-21 05:38:28', `current_sign_in_at` = '2013-09-21 05:38:38', `sign_in_count` = 61, `updated_at` = '2013-09-21 05:38:38' WHERE `users`.`uid` = 149407
   (95.6ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (184.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`authentication_token` = 'uN8QFMsocpDyhWKCx9QN' LIMIT 1
   (93.3ms)  BEGIN
   (109.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/contractor/galleries
Filter chain halted as :after_token_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 10884ms (ActiveRecord: 893.2ms)


Started GET "/contractor/galleries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 22:38:48 -0700
Processing by Contractor::ContractorGalleriesController#index as HTML
Geokit is using the domain:
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/contractor/galleries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 22:38:49 -0700
Processing by Contractor::ContractorGalleriesController#index as HTML
Geokit is using the domain:
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/user/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 22:38:49 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Geokit is using the domain:
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_mixpanel.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (12.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_olark (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 62.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/user/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 22:38:49 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Geokit is using the domain:
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_mixpanel.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (11.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_olark (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 111.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Could you please check @current_user.save is returning true or false value, If it is false then check why it is returning false. This should be true then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from `@user` to `@current_user` in `after_token_authentication`. You're `authenticate_user!` call requires `@current_user` to be set as per here: [where is devise implementation of "authenticate_user!" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272272/where-is-devise-implementation-of-authenticate-user-method)

Comment: SO I had to add: `sign_in @current_user, :bypass => true` http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

This message simply means that within one of your before filters a template was rendered or a redirect happened. In your case, the `after_token_authentication` filter redirected to the `contractor_list_galleries_path`, which ended the chain of before filters. This message is not an error, it is just displayed to tell you that the redirect happened in a before filter not the actual action.

Comment: But then why the user is being redirected to the login screen ?
I'm sure that before the redirection the user is authenticated but he still get a 401 Unauthorized

Comment: The redirect happens after a redirect from the `contractor_list_galleries_path` page, so I can't be sure exactly what is going on. Perhaps the approved attribute is not being set, as I don't see another update sql query occurring for the `@user.save` line.

Comment: Approved is already at 0. So it doens't update it.
But I don't understand why in the redirection the user doesn't have to permission to go to the gallery, even if I signed in him and then the second time it it's the after_token_authentication method he isn't logged in anymore