# What is code for devise authenticate_user! after generated for :user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I realize that `authenticate_user!` is [not explicitly defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272272/where-is-devise-implementation-of-authenticate-user-method) in the gem files, but I am wondering for the typical app (authentication on model named `User`), what would the method look like. I need to know so that I can modify it slightly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you linked to your own answer, the method it defines is

```
def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
  opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
  warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
end
```

Which if we substituted the true class, in your case `User`, it would look like:

```
def authenticate_user!(opts={})
  opts[:scope] = :user
  warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
end
```

So it really calls out to warden and that is where the bulk of the authentication logic lies.

For a typical Rails application, The `authenticate_user!` method will be defined as an `instance_method` on `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 3):

`Devise` uses [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) for authentication. And in order to use it `Devise` provides  own authentication strategies implementing `authenticate!` method. This is what you need. You already have the first part of the code (from the link in your question), which is:

```
  def authenticate_user!(opts={})
    opts[:scope] = :user
    warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
  end
```

In the code above `warden.authenticate!` uses a method coming from `Devise` (implemented by `Devise`) depending on a chosen `Devise` strategy.

For example, the method that implements `DatabaseAuthenticatable` strategy is here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb

the method that implements `Rememberable` strategy is here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/rememberable.rb